# tooltips for the second datasets won't show up chart.js

Tags: javascript, frontend, chart.js

I have a bar diagram made with chart.js that's using two datasets and  for the labels that looks like this.

```
<div><canvas id="myChart"></canvas></div>
```

and the JS for the chart looks like this

```
            const target = [100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100];
            const realisasi = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 10, 1, 0, 0, 0];
            const ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d"); 
            const dataset = {
                    labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
                    datasets: [
                        { label: "Target", data: target, backgroundColor: "#3d8ef8" },
                        { label: "Realisasi", data: testArr, backgroundColor: "#11c46e" },
                    ],
                }       
            const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: dataset,
                options: {
                    tooltips: {
                      callbacks: {
                            data (t, d) {
                                const xLabel = d.datasets[t.datasetIndex].label;
                                const yLabel = t.yLabel >= 1000 ? 'Rp.' + t.yLabel.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',') : '$' + t.yLabel;
                                return xLabel + ': ' + yLabel;
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    scales: {
                        yAxes: [
                          {
                            ticks: {
                            beginAtZero: true,
                            callback: (label, index, labels) => {
                                    return 'Rp.' + label.toFixed(0).toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',');
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                },
            });
```

however the tooltips for the realisasi won't show up when I hover on one of the bar, it only shows the tooltips for the target meanwhile I need to make both tooltips appear when I hover either on the target bar or the realisasi bar. how can I fix that?

Comment: a live example would be very helpful for us trying out solutions. tiny aside: .toFixed(0) returns a string, no need to follow it with `.toString()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define `options.tooltips.mode: 'index'` according to [Chart.js 2.9.4 documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.9.4/general/interactions/modes.html#index).

Please take a look at your amended and runnable code below and see how it works.

```js
const target = [100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100];
const realisasi = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 10, 1, 0, 0, 0];
const dataset = {
  labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
  datasets: [{
      label: "Target",
      data: target,
      backgroundColor: "#3d8ef8"
    },
    {
      label: "Realisasi",
      data: realisasi,
      backgroundColor: "#11c46e"
    },
  ],
}
new Chart('myChart', {
  type: 'bar',
  data: dataset,
  options: {
    tooltips: {
      mode: 'index',
      callbacks: {
        data(t, d) {
          const xLabel = d.datasets[t.datasetIndex].label;
          const yLabel = t.yLabel >= 1000 ? 'Rp.' + t.yLabel.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',') : '$' + t.yLabel;
          return xLabel + ': ' + yLabel;
        }
      }
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
          callback: (label, index, labels) => {
            return 'Rp.' + label.toFixed(0).toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',');
          }
        }
      }]
    },
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="90"></canvas>
```

> Also consider to use a newer version of Chart.js, todays most current stable version is `3.8.0`.